# Detecting incomplete/broken circle using contours

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm trying to detect platelets using functions in **OpenCV 4.0.3**

I managed to get the [original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5e2U.jpg) to this [after applying threshold via inRange function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjrTK.jpg) as I only need the platelets (those purple blobs), but there are still a lot of noise, so I applied a series of morphological operations to reduce noise and regain [details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aoGn.jpg). But there are still a lot of broken circles, is there any functions that will work the given image?

Here's a cropped image for my intended [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKg0K.jpg), those encircled in pink are the detected platelets

Here's my code for reference

```
        Mat plate_img = imread(imagePath, IMREAD_COLOR);
        Mat result = plate_img.clone();
        Mat plate_gradient = new Mat(plate_img.rows(), plate_img.cols(), CV_8UC3, new Scalar(3));
        Mat boosted_plate_gradient =  new Mat();

        GaussianBlur(plate_img, plate_img, new Size(9,9),0);
        morphologyEx(plate_img, plate_img, MORPH_ERODE, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(3,3))); //3 to 5
        morphologyEx(plate_img, plate_gradient, MORPH_GRADIENT, new Mat());

        plate_gradient.convertTo(plate_gradient, -1, 9.5, -60);

        //threshold operation is applied based on the color of the platelets
        cvtColor(plate_gradient,plate_gradient, COLOR_BGR2HSV);
        Scalar low = new Scalar(10,190,190);
        Scalar upper = new Scalar(55,255,255);
        Core.inRange(plate_gradient, low, upper, boosted_plate_gradient);

        //apply operations to lose and regain details
        morphologyEx(boosted_plate_gradient, boosted_plate_gradient, MORPH_DILATE, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(5,5)));
        morphologyEx(boosted_plate_gradient, boosted_plate_gradient, MORPH_CLOSE, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(5,5))); 
        morphologyEx(boosted_plate_gradient, boosted_plate_gradient, MORPH_OPEN, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(7,7))); 
        morphologyEx(boosted_plate_gradient, boosted_plate_gradient, MORPH_CLOSE, getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, new Size(15,15)));

        Mat edges = new Mat();
        Canny(boosted_plate_gradient,edges,250,300,3,false);
        morphologyEx(edges,edges,MORPH_DILATE,getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE,new Size(3,3)));

        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        List<MatOfPoint> finalContour = new ArrayList<>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

        findContours(edges, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        for (MatOfPoint contour:contours) {
            double area = contourArea(contour);

            //platelet size on given image is around these values
            if(area > 100 && area < 750){
                finalContour.add(contour);
            }

        }

        int count = 0;
        cvtColor(edges,edges, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
        for (int i = 0; i < finalContour.size(); i++) {
            count++;
            Scalar color = new Scalar(rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256));
            Imgproc.drawContours(edges, finalContour, i, color, 2, Imgproc.LINE_8, hierarchy, 0, new Point());
        }
```

Comment: What does the expected output looks like ?

Comment: The recent edit should now show them @ZdaR